# Using siunitx with \pgfplotstablegetelem

Tags: siunitx, pgfplotstable

I would like to use `siunitx` package to merge data/uncertainty pairs available from an external file (using precision and rounding options as shown).

It seems like the content of the variable (both defined using `def`) is different if initialised using a hard-coded number or read from a table (`pgfplotstable`); as the latter breaks the code (see last commented line).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{drop-zero-decimal,round-mode=uncertainty,round-precision=1,uncertainty-mode=separate}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    x   dx
    10.1    0.02
    21.2    4.1
    32.3    0.6
}\loadedtable
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={x,dx}]\loadedtable
\vspace{1cm}

\def\varTableA{\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of{\loadedtable}\pgfplotsretval}
\def\varTableB{\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{dx}\of{\loadedtable}\pgfplotsretval}

\def\varA{10.1}
\def\varB{0.02}

% What I would like to do, using values obtained from a table (external file) instead of hard coded values.
\num{10.1 +- 0.02} \\ % Gives the desired output
\num{\varA +- \varB}  % Gives the desired output

% One verifies that the variables contain the correct value -> all good
\varA \qquad \varTableA \\ % Gives 10.1 and 10.1
\varB \qquad \varTableB \\ % Gives 0.02 and 0.02

% Using `parse-numbers=false` is not an option
%\num{\varTableA +- \varTableB} % Doesn't work

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of{\loadedtable}\let\varTableA\pgfplotsretval` or use `\pgfplotsretval` directly inside `siunitx`' commands.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! Do you know "why" it didn't work using \def? Maybe you can write your comment as an answer for me to validate it.

Comment: Since \pgfplotstableretval is defined using \edef, any resulting \def will not be expandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(La)TeX is not a programming language and

```
\def\macro{\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of{\loadedtable}}
% or even
\def\macro{\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of{\loadedtable}\pgfplotsretval}
```

is not the same as

```java
double variable = myTable.getRow(0).getColumn("x").getValue();
```

You can't usually `\def` or `\edef` a macro to something that may typeset the correct content onto the page and assume said macro to be just the text of that output.

The line

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of{\loadedtable}\pgfplotsretval
```

does two distinctive things:

1. Just

   ```
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{x}\of{\loadedtable}
   ```

   defines `\pgfplotsretval` to be the content of row `0` and column `x` (here `10.1`).
2. Then you call

   ```
   \pgfplotsretval
   ```

   and that will expand to its content.

   If it's just somewhere around normal text
   it will output this onto the page.

   If used as

   ```
   \num{\pgfplotsretval}
   ```

   the `siunitx` package will process it somehow and maybe print something totally different onto the page (here it adds a zero: `10.10`).

The `\num` macro of `siunitx` expects only numbers in its argument (unless `parse-numbers = false`).
However, you *feed* it the whole `\pgfplotstablegetelem` expansion. And that's just not a raw number for a multitude of reasons.

---

You will need to do `\pgfplotstablegetelem` outside of any `siunitx` macros and either use `\pgfplotsretval` directly in a `\num` (not possible here because you need two of those) or

- `\edef\varTableA{\pgfplotsretval}` or
- `\let\varTableA\pgfplotsretval`.

If you need this more often I suggest a macro like `\pgfplotstableelem` as I did in the code below.

---

*Note:* The [`pgfplotstable` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgfplotstable/0) states about `\pgfplotstablegetelem`:

> If possible, avoid using this command inside of loops. It is quite slow.

This is not a problem in this small example but depending on your real use-case there might be better ways to read and typeset the contents of your table.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  drop-zero-decimal,
  round-mode       = uncertainty,
  round-precision  = 1,
  uncertainty-mode = separate
}
\pgfplotstableread{
    x   dx
    10.1    0.02
    21.2    4.1
    32.3    0.6
}\loadedtable
\def\pgfplotstableelem#1\to#2{%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem#1\let#2\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{document}
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={x,dx}]\loadedtable
%\vspace{1cm}

\pgfplotstableelem{0}{x}\of{\loadedtable}\to{\varTableA}
\pgfplotstableelem{0}{dx}\of{\loadedtable}\to{\varTableB}

\def\varA{10.1}
\def\varB{0.02}

% What I would like to do, using values obtained from a table (external file) instead of hard coded values.
\num{10.1 +- 0.02} \\ % Gives the desired output
\num{\varA +- \varB}  % Gives the desired output

% One verifies that the variables contain the correct value -> all good
\varA \qquad \varTableA \\ % Gives 10.1 and 10.1
\varB \qquad \varTableB \\ % Gives 0.02 and 0.02

% Using `parse-numbers=false` is not an option
\num{\varTableA +- \varTableB} % ← !
\end{document}
```